# categorical data cannot be >1-dimensional

Tags: python, categorical-data

This following command is saying that my categorical data cannot be >1-dimensional.

My categorical variables here are : law_lag (effective year of a law in a few states of the USA ) , year and statefip ( which is 20 years from 1990-2010 across 50 states [statefip ] of the United States ).

Can anyone tell me if there are any basic issues I'm missing here to address ? At a beginner level , there's a high chance I'll miss the basic stuff.

These are the info for my variables btw from my Dataframe after putting the info command:

```
year      93585   non-null object 
statefip  93585   non-null category 
law_lag   92924   non-null float32
```

My regression command - which is returning me the main error mentioned in the header- is the following one :

```
PH = PH[~pd.isnull(PH.ln_incwage)] 

PH_male = PH[PH.male==1] formula = ( "ln_incwage ~ C(law_lag)*C(year) + C(statefip) + hispanic + asian + ismarried + lths + hsdegree + somecollege + age2" ) 

reg = ( smf .wls(formula, data=PH_male, weights=PH.black.values) .fit( cov_type='cluster', 

cov_kwds={'groups': PH_male.fip.values}, method='pinv') )

reg.summary()
```

Comment: Please supply the expected [minimal, reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) (MRE).
We should be able to copy and paste a contiguous block of your code, execute that file, and reproduce your problem along with tracing output for the problem points.  This lets us test our suggestions against your test data and desired output.
Show where the intermediate results differ from what you expected.

Answer (score 1):

In case it's helpful to anyone, I encountered this error in an unexpected way. While transforming a dataframe, I accidentally wrote:

```
df.columns = [['Column A', 'Column B']]
```

in double brackets instead of single. This caused the error. I can't help but wonder how many others have had this happen.